# If $\lambda$ is an unramified quasi character of $\mathbb{Q}_{p}^{*}$, then $\exists$ s $\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\lambda(a)=|a|^{s}$.

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory

Definitions: A quasi character on $\mathbb{Q}_{p}^{*}$ is a continuous group homomorphism $\lambda: \mathbb{Q}_{p}^{*} \to \mathbb{C}^{*}.$ A quasi character is unramified if $\lambda(\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{*})=1$. $|\cdot|$ is the p-adic absolute value.

Question: If $\lambda$ is an unramified quasi character of $\mathbb{Q}_{p}^{*}$, then $\exists$ s $\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\lambda(a)=|a|^{s}$.

Attempt: Let $ a \in \mathbb{Q}_{p}*$. Thus $a= p^{t}u$ where $t \in \mathbb{Z}$, $u \in\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{*}$. Then $\lambda(a)=\lambda(p^{t})=\lambda(p)^{t}$. I have no idea how to proceed from here. We know that $|a|=p^{-t}.$ So $\lambda(a)=\lambda(\frac{1}{|a|})$. But it doesn't seem this leads us anywhere. Any help/hint will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've shown that $\lambda$ is completely determined by $\lambda(p)$. Say that $\lambda(p)=\alpha$. Then $\alpha = p^{-\log \alpha/\log p}$. So you can take $s = \log \alpha/\log p$.

Comment: I guess the negative sign was a mistake but other than that yup, it was just a nice manipulation. Thank you very much. But a question tho. Does log $\alpha$ make sense? as alpha is a complex number right?(Like we can always take complex logarithm so I guess it works but still wanted to confirm)

Comment: Yeah - I was trying to use $|p| = p^{-1}$, but I guess I lost a sign somewhere. You'll have to choose a branch of logarithm to define $\log \alpha$, but the choice won't affect that value of $|a|^s$, since for $t\in\mathbb Z$, $|p^t|^s = |p^t|^{s + 2\pi i/\log p}$.